# Does an incompatible CoreData store always cause a crash?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject

**Problem:**

We recently introduced CoreData into our app, and previously released a version with an incomplete CoreData model. In that shipped version, we never implemented code to write data to the sqlite database, only the model was implemented.

In our internal testing, we would revert our devices to the previously shipped incomplete model, and then update to the newer model, and never had to perform a migration, nor did we encounter an incompatible store exception.

However, in our beta testing, we have identified existing users that are experiencing crashes due to an incompatible store, while some existing users are not.

**Question:**

Does an incompatible store always cause a crash and if so, why do we not experience a crash when updating to a different CoreData model from an older version?

I should mention that when we make changes to the most recent CoreData model, we do get thrown incompatible store errors, but when we revert to a very primitive version of our core data model, we do not see this exception thrown.

Comment: when u make any changes in coredata then u have to remove old build and use new build if u still use old build so it will lead u to the crash.

Comment: have a look at : https://www.raywenderlich.com/27657/how-to-perform-a-lightweight-core-data-migration

Comment: If you delete the app of your device before installing, then it there is no CoreData schema conflicts so no crash. If your test users didn't delete the app off their device before using the new version of the app which has a different CoreData schema, then the conflict in schema will cause a crash.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, if you have the following line of code called in your project

```
[__persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                                    configuration:nil
                                                              URL:storeURL
                                                          options:nil
                                                            error:&error])
```

code that is automatically added by Xcode when you setup a project with `CoreData` then yes, incompatible store will always cause crash, unless you do a light migration or a heavy migration, depending on your case.

A light migration is quite simple and straight forward, but you have to respect some rules. For light migration you change the above line of code to:

```
 [__persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                                        configuration:nil
                                                                  URL:storeURL
                                                              options:@{NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption:@YES, NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption:@YES}
                                                                error:&error])
```

You can check more about lightweight migration on [developer.apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmLightweightMigration.html)

Also you should check out the link posted by @raki in the comments.

Comment: Thanks, danypata. Looking back at our our shipped incomplete core data build, we have code that declares the persistent store coordinator, but it is never called. Would this be why we only see a crash for some users, but not all?

Our plan of action is to completely remove the persistent store (if it is incompatible), then create a new one and load data from our servers as the migration would probably be heavy. We already sync local data with our external servers, so the code is plug and play. Thoughts on this approach?

Comment: I don't know why it's crashing if the code is never called, it means that the core data is not set up at all, the crash might be from other places. Regarding the recreating the persistent store, in my opinion, if you don't use the core data relations (one-to-many, many-to-many), I would go for direct cache in files since you sync all the data with your servers. Also a much better alternative for core data is Realm (check it out) and it's incredible fast, but like core data you have to handle migration, actually I don't think there's a cache method that doesn't request some sort of migration.